# Getting a Div height and applying to the style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have managed to stick together the following code from various sources, but now I'm completely stuck!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var return_height = $("#columns").outerHeight();
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
a[0].innerHTML += return_height;
});
```

The current code will return the value within the first 'p' tag. I need the value to be returned on a specific div like this;

```
<div id="column-container" style="height: return_height ">
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You want to access a <div> , but you are use 'p' as TagName?

Comment: Please check out http://try.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com. This question is very simple and unnecessarily combines native JavaScript with jQuery.

Comment: when you are using using jquery why not use it. instead of javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var return_height = $("#columns").outerHeight();
 $('#column-container').height(return_height);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("column-container").style.height = return_height + "px";
```

Using jQuery

```
$("#column-container").height(return_height);
```

Comment: y not use jquery when its available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.css()` method to set the height of your div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#column-container').css('height', $("#columns").outerHeight());
});
```

`.height()` works, too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#column-container').height($("#columns").outerHeight());
});
```